# After sleep mode or hibernation blender crashes

Tags: error, performance, windows, system

When working on projects, I don't close the necessary programs and folders when i want have a rest so that after the rest I can get to work faster. I use hibernation when I go to sleep, and sleep mode when I leave for a short time. And blender is one of the necessary programs that I almost never closed, but recently i upgraded to Windows 11 and now blender closes automatically after the PC exits sleep or hibernation mode its like crashes with no signs of it was opened before. Blender 3.5.1 steam version. Perhaps someone faced such a problem, would be very grateful for help.

Comment: Does it produce a crash file in C:\Users\[LOGIN]\AppData\Local\Temp\[blend_filename].crash.txt ?   I use win11 and with sleep and hibernate modes and do not have this problem, even with active blender background jobs running (render or python scripts to back fluids).   You can submit the crash file via blender::Help::SubmitBug.

Comment: To be honest I wouldn't trust any hibernation to keep anything more than a cube.

Comment: I also wouldn't trust "upgraded" systems (as opposed to fresh installed ones), nor Windows to be able to correctly wake up graphics card after hibernation. This has most likely nothing to do with Blender itself, and is likely an operating system or driver issue with failing to wake up OpenGL context after system resume

Comment: james_t thanks for the help but unfortunately it's not producing any crash file, i repeat the bug many times and no file at all

Answer (score 0):

We can't do much about it here.

You can use the menu Help > [Report A Bug](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports) and file a bug report to the developers team. Maybe it's something wrong in Blender they can fix.
If you want to do that, you probably first should try to follow the [crashes troubleshooting procedure](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/crash.html) by running Blender with one of the .bat files that should provide a more complete crash log.

I think the command line opened by these files stays open even after Blender crashes. But to be safe, you can :

- <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> a blank area in the folder
- Open Terminal Here
- Type the full name of the .bat file and <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>

It will run that file in an independent terminal that won't close). This way, even if the crash log file isn't created for some reason, the terminal should display what would have been written in it, and you can manually copy it. Don't forget to mention that the crash log wasn't created in your bug report.

But it could also just be your system. Like [a faulty hibernation procedure](https://pureinfotech.com/fix-hibernate-problems-windows-10/), or even just your hardware unable to do something the system asks it to. But that's out of topic on this website.